# java jms client 0.28 destination syntax

Tags: java, jms, client, amqp, qpid

I need to use the Java JMS client (0.28) to connect to a AMQP broker (Java or C++)

In my receiver I have the following destination string which creates a headers queue and binds to the exchange without any problem.

```
myapp_queue;{create:receiver,delete:always,node:{type:queue,x-bindings:[{exchange:'amq.match',arguments:{x-match:all,name:'dave'}}]}}
```

However as my sender should only need to know the exchange and the headers, I cannot workout the syntax to send to the headers exchange using my header. I have the following:

```
exchange:'amq.match',arguments:{x-match:all,name:'dave'}
```

...but I get a JMS connection exception can anyone help please?

Comment: `amq.match` is headers based routing exchange, shouldn't you be setting `name=dave` on the message header rather then on the sender connection string?